# Attaching armv7 static library to Monotouch project

Tags: xamarin.ios, static-libraries, armv7

I have 3rd party static library compiled for i386 and armv7 architectures (without armv6). Is there a way to link Monotouch project with armv7 library? Monotouch adds '-arch armv6' parameter to gcc and I don't know how to change it.

Answer (score 2):

The current release of monotouch supports all existing iPhones and thus compiles for armv6 since it runs everywhere.

The next major release will support targeting armv7 specific binaries.